# Gmail Timed Filters to Delete msgs between 8am - 5pm

Tags: email, gmail-api

How can I set up something in gmail to delete msgs that match a gmail filter between 8am - 5pm

I was thinking it might be possible to do it through a google apps script and was wondering if anyone has already made anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through the top threads (maximum of 20 unfortunately) and check the date-time stamp on them and then you can delete them using the [`delete` api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete) which would be relatively simple.

```
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
    OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
    STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials = STORAGE.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    threads = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me', maxResults=1).execute()
    if threads['threads']:
        for thread in threads['threads']:
```

The code I've written for you here does the easy part for you, all you need to do is check the [date-time](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-gmail) of that particular message, and then decide if you want to [delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete) it.